# PHP class not found but class file successfully included

Tags: php, class

I have downloaded a very small sample file that I am using while trying to get PHPWord to work.  I am getting the following error message and can't figure out why.

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPWord' not found in /var/www/html/PhpOffice/ex_01.php on line 6

My downloaded small sample program is:

```
<?php
  require_once 'PhpWord.php';

  echo realpath (dirname(__FILE__)) . "\n";

  $PHPWord = new PHPWord();     <-- <-- <-- LINE 6 HERE
  $section = $PHPWord->createSection();
  $section->addText('Hello world!');
  header("Cache-Control: public");
  header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=helloWorld.docx");
  header("Content-Type: application/docx");
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
  $objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
  $objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');
?>
```

The internet distributed PhpWord.php file is a bit large for posting but the key point is that lines 43 and 44 and lower contain class code with matching spelling and matching upper/lower case:

```
class PHPWord
{
```

For debugging purposes I am running the code from the command line.  This seems to give me meaningful error messages.

The "require" seems to be finding the file.  The "echo dirname" is posting " /var/www/html/PhpOffice" which is the correct location of both files.  In addition, as an experiment I added a typo to the file name in the "require" statement and this caused a "file not found" error.  Thus, the "require" looks good.

I have some experience with PHP but this is the first time I have read about classes and namespace in PHP.  So far I have no idea what is going wrong.  Any suggestions?

Thank you,
Bruce

Comment: IIRC, I recently solved a similar problem by checking the source code, and noticing it was opened with `<?` instead of `<?php` , which works IF your php.ini is set up to handle it -- which mine wasn't. Maybe check that?

Comment: PHPWord  is namespaced.... you need to reference the class by its full namespaced name.... `$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();` Try looking at some of the Examples in the `/samples` folder

Comment: With new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PHPWord();     I am now getting:    PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings' not found in /var/www/html/PhpOffice/ex_01.php on line 6.       I will have to do some digging but I suspect that my first problem is solved and I am now failing on lower level calls.    I am still a bit confused with namespace and obviously I don't have something right in my install if the distributed PhpWord files don't run due to internal code.

Answer (score 1):

> first time I have read about classes and namespace in PHP

If in the `PhpWord.php` is something like `namespace XYZ`;
Then you have too do place `use \XYZ\PHPWord;` in the first lines of your script.

If you are within a namespace and the class has no, then you have to use `$PHPWord = new \PHPWord();`

If you dont have an `autoloader` you have too include all the files that belonging to `PHPOffice` and then you can use `use \PHPOffice\PHPWord();`

Comment: I am still trying to grasp the namespace issues and pitfalls but here are the only "use" and "namespace" lines that I found in PhpWord.php.

Comment: namespace PhpOffice\PhpWord;

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Section; 
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Exception\Exception;

Comment: So even if the class file is found I still need to add a "use" to allow the class within the class file to be loaded?

Comment: Can you build a Autoloader?

Comment: I saw Autoloader in several postings on the Internet but so far I have not read any Autoloader tutorials and don't have any idea how to build, run or debug one.

Comment: I'll read up on Autoloader and give that a try.  I have to leave the computer for a few hours.  Thank you everyone for the help so far and I'll post my results or refined questions as soon as I can.

Comment: Note that PHPWord is written for installation with composer and use of the composer autoloader

Comment: I would simply use the [composer autoloader](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) instead of building something myself. By using existing tools I have more time for the things that make my apps unique.

Answer (score -1):

The solution for remote server (I fixed my issue for GoDaddy):

If you are using cpanel you may have zip extension installed but not activate. You need to active it. For this case you need to go to cpanel > inside software section > click on PHP version. Then find zip and check it. Now save.

[image: You should see like the image.]

Refresh your application page.

Comment: Why should a PHP class named `PHPWord` became available after activating a PHP extension? That does not make any sense

Comment: Nico Haase why you down voted? It works for me without any problem by enabling the zip extension.

Comment: As I said: according to the given error message (and not any other similar use case that only looked the same but was completely different), enabling a PHP extension can not be the core solution